# How to get the dates of a particular month

Tags: vba, date, excel

I am working in a excel macro. In that I need to generate all the dates belong to a particular month. Can anybody say how to achieve that?

**UPDATE:**
      I want to receive it as an array of numbers. I tried to use Date related function which were under namespace "System". But, it is showing error as "object or method not found". So, I am using Issan's idea(see below). But, I am getting error as "Object doesn't support this property or method".

**EDIT:**
      The "Object doesn't support this property or method" error went out after I declared a variable as Date. I think the available objects in VBA are depend on declared variables. Thank you to all of you.

Comment: @downvoter A request to all the downvoters. If you mention the fact for the downvote then only downvote has some meaning. Else It is something like a childplay.

Comment: Just create a `for` loop from `1` to `NumberOfDaysInMonth`? P.S. I did not downvote you so far, but your question could be really improved.

Comment: @Doc_Brown That's all I need. I am very new to VB. And I didn't find any example for that. I forgot to add that I am a beginner.

Comment: Hi prabhakaran, I wouldn't downvote a question like this. However, some people might because you haven't yet shown what you've done so far. Personally, I think if you took a look at this:  
http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=400  then it will return the number of days in a month. You can then loop around these days to generate a date - i.e. Sep 2011 returns 30, which means you can just do 1 Sep 2011, 2 Sep 2011, ... 30 Sep 2011. Hope that helps.

Comment: @prabhakaran: *What* do you need? A function for "NumberOfDaysInMonth"? Which type of parameter should this function have? Or do you have problems how to add the index to a date? Please edit your question accordingly, and you will get good answers instead of downvotes.

Comment: Language? VB? VBA? VB.Net? How are you working with a macro I not VBA? Interop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Assuming you meant VBA since you say you are 'working in an Excel macro')

Here's how you can generate an array of Dates for each day in a particular month (there's not enough info to suggest what format you want so I am assuming an array of dates).

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Dim Days() As Date
Dim DaysInMonth As Long, i As Long
Dim Year As Long, Month As Long

' Example: Feb, 2006 (leap year)
Year = 1996
Month = 2

DaysInMonth = DateSerial(Year, Month + 1, 1) - _
              DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)

ReDim Days(1 To DaysInMonth)
For i = 1 To DaysInMonth
    Days(i) = DateSerial(Year, Month, i)
Next

'Do as you wish with the array of 29 days

End Sub
```

**How it works:**
You can get the number of days in a month using the dateserial math above. This will ensure that you get the proper amount of days, even considering leap years. Then you just redim your array of days and populate the array!

Comment: I am getting error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Maybe it's happening at the example transpose part? That might be dependent on your version of excel - what exactly do you want though? An array of dates to work with within VBA?

Comment: I deleted the example at the end - it wasn't practical anyway :)

Comment: If your on, please explain in your question what you actually need (an array, a column, strings, etc.) and how you plan to use it.

Comment: I think VBA. I just right clicked the worksheet(name) and clicked "View Code". Then I am working on it.

Comment: Everything works now. See the edit. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use VBA, then Issun's answer is the best way to handle this.

Yet, this is probably part of a bigger issue and from your question, we can't see what you want to achieve.

Don't forget that you can also use the Excel Spreadsheet to help you building a whole application.

For instance, you could use the **formula** `=EOMONTH(NOW(),0)` to get the last day of the current month. Or adapt it the way you want on any other date.
*Note :* don't forget to check the `Analysis ToolPak Add-in` so that the `EOMONTH` formula will exist.

[EDIT] You can find some more info about `EOMONTH` on [this blog's article](http://excel-formulas.blogspot.com/2005/08/excel-last-day-of-month-formula.html)